# ORA-12152: TNS: unable to send break message - Only LISTENER restart works

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, windows-server, listener

i have a strange problem with our Oracle 12.1.0.1.0 on our VM Windows Server 2016.

I create a daily batch script whichs creates a dump file (via EXP) and execute some sql statements (via SQLPlus).

After a few hours the batch scripts doesnt work anymore. So i try to start the batch manually to see what happens. The login at SQLPlus and EXP returns this error message:

> ORA-12152: TNS: unable to send break message

So i try to start SQLPlus manually, but i get the same error, if i try to connect as USER@SID.

My application which uses a direct database drivers works fine. So the database in the background works.

I think its a problem with the listener, because if i restart the listener (lsnrctl restart) sqlplus and exp works, but after a few hours the problem comes back.

Listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = O:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:O:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MY_HOSTNAME)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Sqlnet.ora:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Tnsnames.ora:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MY_HOSTNAME)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Edit 1:

lsnrctl stat:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 17-JAN-2022 08:41:48

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Anmeldung bei (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS: Kein Listener
 TNS-12560: TNS: Fehler bei Protokolladapter
  TNS-00511: Kein Listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Anmeldung bei (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVER)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS des LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Startdatum                13-JAN-2022 15:55:54
Uptime                    3 Tage 16 Std. 45 Min. 56 Sek.
Trace-Ebene               off
Sicherheit                ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Parameterdatei des Listener O:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Log-Datei des Listener    O:\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\SERVER\listener\alert\log.xml
Zusammenfassung Listening-Endpunkte...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=SERVER)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=SERVER)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=O:\ORACLE\admin\ORCL\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Übersicht...
Dienst "CLRExtProc" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "CLRExtProc", Status UNKNOWN, hat 1 Handler f³r diesen Dienst...
Dienst "ORCL" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Dienst "ORCLXDB" hat 1 Instanzen.
  Instanz "orcl", Status READY, hat 1 Handler für diesen Dienst...
Der Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgef³hrt.
```

Log from listener\alert\log.xml:

```
<msg time='2022-01-17T08:48:46.567+01:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='SERVER'
 host_addr='XXXX::XXXX:XXX:XXXX:606b%3'>
 <txt>17-JAN-2022 08:48:46 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=O:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\sqlplus.exe)(HOST=SERVER)(USER=Administrator))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:606b%3)(PORT=59736)) * establish * orcl * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

TRC file:
https://pastebin.com/8rdvmEm3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error happening, local error, no antivirus.

It was resolved after changing the parameter `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES` to `(NONE)` in sqlnet.ora